# Access SharePoint Documents from ASP.net

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, secure-store

As per current requirement, I have a sharepoint 2013 On Premise site open to internet for a perticular domain users. I want to retrieve documents from a document library from an worl wide web ASP.Net Web Site using CSOM.

My Concern is that how I can manage the authentication? Do I require to configure Secure Store service?

ASP.Net users are not the part of the domain in which SharePoint is hosted.

Comment: Online or On-premise?

Comment: On-Premise Enviroment

Comment: The Secure Store service will not help because it is for maintaining credentials for target applications that SharePoint need to access. For example, this service is good for storing credentials that you use to access external system via the Business Data Connectivity Service. In your case, you want to access SharePoint from your application. I don't really have experience with this so I cannot help.

Comment: What about if I enable anonymous access to SharePoint Site?